# Encapsulate a string into a div bubble using html

Tags: c#, html, blazor-server-side

I want users to be able to enter keywords for a product. Each keyword is separated by a ','. As the user types the keywords they become isolated in a little bubble and shown to the user as such.

```
   <label for="KeywordsInput">Keywords:</label>
                    <InputText id="KeywordsInput" @bind-Value="product.Keywords" maxlength="3000" onfocus="@ChangeHelpNoteVisibility" onblur="@ChangeHelpNoteVisibility" oninput="@IsKeywordComplete" ></InputText>              
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => product.Keywords)" />
                    <p class="keywordHelpNote" hidden=@keywordHelpNoteHidden>Sepearte keywords with a comma</p>
                          
                    
                    <div class="bubble">test
                        <span class="bubbleclosebtn" onclick="@DeleteKeyword">&times;</span>
                    </div> 

  
 private string[] IsKeywordComplete(string allKeywords)
    {
        string[] condition = { "," };
        string[] keywords = allKeywords.Split(condition, StringSplitOptions.None);

        return keywords;
    }

    private void DeleteKeyword(string keywordToDelete)
    {
        keywords = keywords.Where(val => val != keywordToDelete).ToArray();
    }
```

This is based off the stack overflow add tags feature when you ask a question.

Comment: Do you mean a Badge? 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_badges_labels.asp

Comment: No I want each keyword to be its own separate bubble. If you ask a question on stack overflow add a tag... this is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="tableResults">
    <label>@users.Count() results for:</label>

    <div class="bubble" id="NameBubble" hidden="@searchNameHidden">
        @filters.Name
        <span class="bubbleclosebtn" @onclick="@ResetSearchBar">&times;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bubble" id="InactiveBubble" hidden="@searchInactiveBubbleHidden">
        Inactive
    </div>

    <div class="bubble" id="ActiveBubble" hidden="@searchActiveBubbleHidden">
        Active
    </div>
       
</div>


/*Bubble Search Filters*/
.bubble {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #c8daea;
    color: #437dad;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: max-content;
    border-radius: 28px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.bubbleclosebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-top:3.1px;
}

.bubbleclosebtn:hover {
    color: #437dad;
    background-color: #a7c4dd;
}
```